# Google Firebase WAR file deployment

Tags: firebase, war, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to deploy a single WAR file to Google Firebase instead of a whole directory?
The war file contains the following files:

- assets directory
- META-INF directory
- WEB-INF directory
- index.html
- some JS files (chunks, inline, main, polyfills, vendor)
- styles.css

In my case it is an Angular 5 website, that I've build with angular-cli. My current deployment to firebase requires me to upload 19 files (the whole dist directory). I want to reduce that to one WAR file, which I can build with gulp.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What's in the war?  What Firebase product are you deploying to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Hosting only supports deploying an entire directory structure using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying).  WAR files are typically used to deploy to a J2EE container, and Firebase Hosting is definitely not that.